# Can't Flash Google Factory Image - No Boot Partition

Tags: boot-loop, boot, fastboot, factory-image

I seem to have bricked my phone but thankfully the bootloader is unlocked so I'm sure there is a way to fix it. I am having a hell of a time though, I think I need to re-create the boot partition manually. Here is what I get when I try `flash-all.bat`

I can't find instructions how to re-create partitions, but I noticed this in `fastboot --help`, does anybody have experience creating partitons with fastboot? And/Or can somebody get the partition map from their device and/or share/extrapolate the commands needed.

```
  erase <partition>                        Erase a flash partition.
  format[:[<fs type>][:[<size>]] <partition>
                                           Format a flash partition. Can
                                           override the fs type and/or size
                                           the bootloader reports.
```

I get the same in both `slot_a` and `slot_b` and I have manually flashed `bootloader.img` & `boot.img`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>flash-all.bat
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'bootloaderb' (36336 KB)...
OKAY [  0.156s]
writing 'bootloaderb'...
OKAY [  0.516s]
finished. total time: 0.672s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.016s
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'radiob' (60388 KB)...
OKAY [  0.261s]
writing 'radiob'...
OKAY [  0.837s]
finished. total time: 1.101s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.002s]
finished. total time: 0.003s
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
archive does not contain 'recovery.img'
archive does not contain 'system.sig'
archive does not contain 'vendor.sig'
wiping userdata...
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 120909180928
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 8192
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 32768
    Label:
    Blocks: 29518843
    Block groups: 901
    Reserved block group size: 1024
Created filesystem with 11/7380992 inodes and 511380/29518843 blocks
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: TMZ20k
Baseband Version.....: g8998-00253-1809191716
Serial Number........: 710KPMZ0311515
--------------------------------------------
checking product...
OKAY [  0.000s]
checking version-bootloader...
OKAY [  0.000s]
checking version-baseband...
OKAY [  0.000s]
sending 'bootb' (40960 KB)...
OKAY [  0.188s]
writing 'bootb'...
FAILED (remote: No such partition.)
finished. total time: 0.219s
Press any key to exit...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm into TWRP but still things awry, but this post is resolved. I had to specify `boot_a` or it tried to use `boota`.

```
fastboot format:ext4 boot_a
fastboot flash boot_a boot.img
```

Finally got fully back to stock, which is what I like to do after a soft brick. I did it by manually typing `fastboot flash foo_a foo.img` for EVERY IMAGE. Then I finished by re-locking the bootloader.

Note: It's scary to lock bootloader while softbricked but I can confirm I have locked/failed to fix brick/re-unlocked bootloader from Fastboot. As long as your "brick" starts with the bootloader unlocked you should be good!

Here is my rediclous fix of my problem:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot flash boot boot.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'boota' (40960 KB)...
OKAY [  0.156s]
writing 'boota'...
FAILED (remote: No such partition.)
finished. total time: 0.156s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot --slot:boot_aflash boot boot.img
fastboot: unknown option -- slot:boot_aflash

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot --slot:boot_a flash boot boot.img
fastboot: unknown option -- slot:boot_a

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot --slot boot_a flash boot boot.img
Slot boot_a does not exist. supported slots are:
a
b


C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot --slot a flash boot boot.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'boota' (40960 KB)...
OKAY [  0.172s]
writing 'boota'...
FAILED (remote: No such partition.)
finished. total time: 0.172s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot --slot all flash boot boot.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'boota' (40960 KB)...
OKAY [  0.156s]
writing 'boota'...
FAILED (remote: No such partition.)
finished. total time: 0.172s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot erase boot
erasing 'boota'...
FAILED (remote: Check device console.)
finished. total time: 0.000s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot erase boot_a
erasing 'boot_a'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.031s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot erase boot_b
erasing 'boot_b'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.016s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot flash boot_a boot.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'boot_a' (40960 KB)...
OKAY [  0.156s]
writing 'boot_a'...
OKAY [  0.577s]
finished. total time: 0.733s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot flash boot_b boot.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'boot_b' (40960 KB)...
OKAY [  0.172s]
writing 'boot_b'...
OKAY [  0.562s]
finished. total time: 0.750s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash bootloader bootloader-taimen-tmz20k.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'bootloaderb' (36336 KB)...
OKAY [  0.141s]
writing 'bootloaderb'...
OKAY [  0.531s]
finished. total time: 0.672s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot reboot-bootloader
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.000s]
finished. total time: 0.000s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot flash radio_a radio-taimen-g8998-00253-1809191716.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'radio_a' (60388 KB)...
OKAY [  0.219s]
writing 'radio_a'...
OKAY [  0.859s]
finished. total time: 1.078s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot flash radio_b radio-taimen-g8998-00253-1809191716.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'radio_b' (60388 KB)...
OKAY [  0.235s]
writing 'radio_b'...
OKAY [  0.859s]
finished. total time: 1.094s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot reboot-bootloader
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.000s]
finished. total time: 0.000s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash boot_a boot.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'boot_a' (40960 KB)...
OKAY [  0.156s]
writing 'boot_a'...
OKAY [  0.547s]
finished. total time: 0.703s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash boot_b boot.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'boot_b' (40960 KB)...
OKAY [  0.156s]
writing 'boot_b'...
OKAY [  0.750s]
finished. total time: 0.906s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash vendor_a vendor.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
erasing 'vendor_a'...
OKAY [  0.030s]
sending 'vendor_a' (360328 KB)...
OKAY [  1.339s]
writing 'vendor_a'...
OKAY [  1.563s]
finished. total time: 2.931s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash vendor_b vendor.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
erasing 'vendor_b'...
OKAY [  0.031s]
sending 'vendor_b' (360328 KB)...
OKAY [  1.354s]
writing 'vendor_b'...
OKAY [  1.542s]
finished. total time: 2.943s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash system_a system.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
erasing 'system_a'...
OKAY [  0.078s]
sending sparse 'system_a' 1/5 (524284 KB)...
OKAY [  2.610s]
writing 'system_a' 1/5...
OKAY [  2.235s]
sending sparse 'system_a' 2/5 (524284 KB)...
OKAY [  2.625s]
writing 'system_a' 2/5...
OKAY [  2.266s]
sending sparse 'system_a' 3/5 (524284 KB)...
OKAY [  2.469s]
writing 'system_a' 3/5...
OKAY [  2.266s]
sending sparse 'system_a' 4/5 (521176 KB)...
OKAY [  2.454s]
writing 'system_a' 4/5...
OKAY [  2.261s]
sending sparse 'system_a' 5/5 (167104 KB)...
OKAY [  0.797s]
writing 'system_a' 5/5...
OKAY [  0.734s]
finished. total time: 20.794s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash system_b system.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
erasing 'system_b'...
OKAY [  0.062s]
sending sparse 'system_b' 1/5 (524284 KB)...
OKAY [  2.469s]
writing 'system_b' 1/5...
OKAY [  2.294s]
sending sparse 'system_b' 2/5 (524284 KB)...
OKAY [  2.453s]
writing 'system_b' 2/5...
OKAY [  2.250s]
sending sparse 'system_b' 3/5 (524284 KB)...
OKAY [  2.453s]
writing 'system_b' 3/5...
OKAY [  2.250s]
sending sparse 'system_b' 4/5 (521176 KB)...
OKAY [  2.449s]
writing 'system_b' 4/5...
OKAY [  2.276s]
sending sparse 'system_b' 5/5 (167104 KB)...
OKAY [  0.781s]
writing 'system_b' 5/5...
OKAY [  0.734s]
finished. total time: 20.474s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash modem_a modem.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'modem_a' (60380 KB)...
OKAY [  0.231s]
writing 'modem_a'...
OKAY [  1.312s]
finished. total time: 1.543s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash modem_b modem.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'modem_b' (60380 KB)...
OKAY [  0.250s]
writing 'modem_b'...
OKAY [  1.328s]
finished. total time: 1.578s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash abl_a abl.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'abl_a' (540 KB)...
OKAY [ -0.000s]
writing 'abl_a'...
OKAY [  0.031s]
finished. total time: 0.031s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash --slot all abl.img
unknown partition 'abl.img'
error: cannot determine image filename for 'abl.img'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe --slot all flash abl.img
unknown partition 'abl.img'
error: cannot determine image filename for 'abl.img'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash abl_b abl.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'abl_b' (540 KB)...
OKAY [  0.016s]
writing 'abl_b'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.031s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash aes_a aes.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'aes_a' (48 KB)...
OKAY [ -0.000s]
writing 'aes_a'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.016s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash aes_b aes.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'aes_b' (48 KB)...
OKAY [  0.000s]
writing 'aes_b'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.016s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash cmnlib_a cmnlib.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'cmnlib_a' (220 KB)...
OKAY [ -0.000s]
writing 'cmnlib_a'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.016s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash cmnlib_b cmnlib.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'cmnlib_b' (220 KB)...
OKAY [ -0.000s]
writing 'cmnlib_b'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.016s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash cmnlib64_a cmnlib64.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'cmnlib64_a' (288 KB)...
OKAY [  0.016s]
writing 'cmnlib64_a'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.031s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash cmnlib64_b cmnlib64.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'cmnlib64_b' (288 KB)...
OKAY [ -0.000s]
writing 'cmnlib64_b'...
OKAY [  0.017s]
finished. total time: 0.017s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash devcfg_a devcfg.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'devcfg_a' (60 KB)...
OKAY [ -0.000s]
writing 'devcfg_a'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.016s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash devcfg_b devcfg.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'devcfg_b' (60 KB)...
OKAY [  0.016s]
writing 'devcfg_b'...
OKAY [  0.013s]
finished. total time: 0.029s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash dtbo_a dtbo.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'dtbo_a' (8192 KB)...
OKAY [  0.037s]
writing 'dtbo_a'...
OKAY [  0.109s]
finished. total time: 0.146s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash dtbo_b dtbo.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'dtbo_b' (8192 KB)...
OKAY [  0.031s]
writing 'dtbo_b'...
OKAY [  0.141s]
finished. total time: 0.172s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash hyp_a hyp.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'hyp_a' (264 KB)...
OKAY [  0.000s]
writing 'hyp_a'...
OKAY [  0.020s]
finished. total time: 0.020s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash hyp_b hyp.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'hyp_b' (264 KB)...
OKAY [  0.014s]
writing 'hyp_b'...
OKAY [  0.000s]
finished. total time: 0.015s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash keymaster_a keymaster.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'keymaster_a' (308 KB)...
OKAY [  0.000s]
writing 'keymaster_a'...
OKAY [  0.026s]
finished. total time: 0.026s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash keymaster_b keymaster.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'keymaster_b' (308 KB)...
OKAY [  0.012s]
writing 'keymaster_b'...
OKAY [ -0.000s]
finished. total time: 0.012s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash laf_a laf.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'laf_a' (29800 KB)...
OKAY [  0.125s]
writing 'laf_a'...
OKAY [  0.406s]
finished. total time: 0.547s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash laf_b laf.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'laf_b' (29800 KB)...
OKAY [  0.110s]
writing 'laf_b'...
OKAY [  0.125s]
finished. total time: 0.250s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash pmic_a pmic.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'pmic_a' (52 KB)...
OKAY [ -0.000s]
writing 'pmic_a'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.016s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash pmic_b pmic.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'pmic_b' (52 KB)...
OKAY [ -0.000s]
writing 'pmic_b'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.016s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash rpm_a rpm.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'rpm_a' (232 KB)...
OKAY [  0.016s]
writing 'rpm_a'...
OKAY [  0.009s]
finished. total time: 0.024s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash rpm_b rpm.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'rpm_b' (232 KB)...
OKAY [ -0.000s]
writing 'rpm_b'...
OKAY [  0.000s]
finished. total time: 0.017s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash tz_a tz.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'tz_a' (1868 KB)...
OKAY [  0.016s]
writing 'tz_a'...
OKAY [  0.026s]
finished. total time: 0.045s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash tz_b tz.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'tz_b' (1868 KB)...
OKAY [  0.016s]
writing 'tz_b'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.045s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash vbmeta_a vbmeta.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'vbmeta_a' (4 KB)...
OKAY [ -0.000s]
writing 'vbmeta_a'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.016s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash vbmeta_b vbmeta.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'vbmeta_b' (4 KB)...
OKAY [  0.000s]
writing 'vbmeta_b'...
OKAY [  0.017s]
finished. total time: 0.020s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash xbl_a xbl.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'xbl_a' (2620 KB)...
OKAY [  0.016s]
writing 'xbl_a'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.031s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flash xbl_b xbl.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'xbl_b' (2620 KB)...
OKAY [  0.016s]
writing 'xbl_b'...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.031s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot.exe flashing lock
```